# Rails, pagination of a matrix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a huge (in number of rows) matrix (double array) and I would like to paginate it, so that on first page only first 10 elements are seen.

Example:

```
arrayA = [["a",1,2,3],["b",5,7,8],["c",4,7,3],["d",1,2,9],["e",4,2,6]]
```

On the first page only first two elements of an `arrayA` are seen:

```
["a",1,2,3]
["b",5,7,8]
```

I am not sure I can do it with standard [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gem.

and how I display it in the view?
I have a following structure to display my matrix:

```
<%
    mat = @mat
    mat.each do |line| %>
    <tr>
        <td>            
            <% line.each do |el|%>
            <td class ="table_column_width">
            <%=el%>
            </td>
            <% end %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will_paginate adds a `paginate` method onto array (see https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/array.rb). You may need to `require 'will_paginate/array'` if it's not available.

You should then be able to do

```
# controller...

@results = arrayA.paginate(page: 1, :per_page: 2)

# view....

<% @results.each do |letter, *numbers| %>
  <%= letter %>
  <% numbers.each do |number| %>
    <%= number %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: but how can I display a pagination in the view then? I want to show each element of a matrix as a row. (I added the way I do it in the question)

Comment: @Tonja I've updated my answer w/ an example of how you would loop over this in the view

Answer (score 0):

i personally like to use Kaminari to handle these situations. just add the gem

see this

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

once you added it. you can use it this way

```
arrayA = [["a",1,2,3],["b",5,7,8],["c",4,7,3],["d",1,2,9],["e",4,2,6]]


Kaminari.paginate_array(arrayA).page(1).per(2)
```